# Need help conceptualizing Web API and MVC 5 solution

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, crud

I have been tasked with writing an API to POST new users to an existing database. I have created a separate WEB API 2 project (with MVC) to the main MVC project.

Because I am using an existing database, I used the ADO.NET Entity Data Model (entity framework) database-first approach to generate an .edmx file with my various model class files -- in the API project.

I also want to use the controller scaffolding option, when I create a controller, to automatically create the Views and CRUD operations based on my models. However the models generated by the edmx aren't appearing in the controller configuration: [see image for context](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jvl4X.png).

Lastly, I am not sure how to to *connect* the web API project and the main MVC project such that you can call the API from the main project?

I assume I need to create a controller inside the main MVC project which uses HttpClient package. However, I am sure it is not so simple.

Answer (score 0):

This is really two separate questions, but I'll have a crack at them both...

To use generated classes from an entity framework context in a different project to which they're defined,. you'll need to use normal [.net assembly referencing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx) to reference the API project from the web project. They will also need to be public, fortunately this is the default.

How you access the API at runtime depends completely on your design. If it's a front-end api, designed to be called from the browser, use XMLHTTPRequest or $.ajax() in JavaScript to make an ajax call. If it's a backend API designed to be called by server side code, use [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx). Take note of the documentation where it says:

> HttpClient is intended to be instantiated once and reused throughout the life of an application.

In other words, don't instantiate an HttpClient for every request, create one and share it, it is designed to be reused.

Answer (score -1):

you can use your apis with http client with their names directly in mvc application.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
  client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:12345/api/");
  //HTTP Requests
}
```

Comment: [This is not the right way to use HttpClient](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/)